# Running Spring MVC project on linux VPS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, vps

I have a Spring MVC project (not really small) with a MySQL and want to run it on a linux VPS. I can't find a tutorial of how to do it (i'm using Window and have never touch linux). I had thinked of running Eclipse just like the localhost on the VPS but i don't know if i should do that. Can i get some advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to explain entire tutorial here. However, I can provide major steps involved. You can google detailed steps for these

- Step 1 - Install Mysql on VPS Step 2 - Allow mysql for remote
  connections Step 3 - Add a remote user to mysql server Step 4 -
  Install Java on VPS Step 5 - Install tomcat server on VPS Step 6 -
  Configure new mysql details in application.properties Step 7 - Extend
  your Spring boot application class with SpringBootServletInitializer
  Step 8 - Configure pom.xml to generate war file Step 9 - Run project
  as "Maven Install". A war would be generated Step 10 - Copy the war
  file to {tomcat install path}/webapps folder Step 11 - Restart server
  and tail tomcag logs for any error

Comment: thank you so much, the mysql  remote connections is to access database from my home computer right ? Like for backing up data to my real pc ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to connect SQL database from home computer, you have to add remote user. Else not required.

Comment: hey my project use Spring but it is not Spring boot, do i have to convert it to Spring boot ?